# Return value for asynchronous onload events synchronously?

Tags: javascript, dom-events

Given the following function:

```
function check_min_sizing (input, options) {
  reader = new FileReader();
  reader.onload = function (e) {
    img_rsc = e.target.result;
    image = new Image();
    image.onload = function () {
      if (image.width < options.min_width || image.height < options.min_height) {
        return false;
      } else {
        return true;
      }
    };
    image.src = img_rsc;
  };
  reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
}
```

How can I make the whole function return `true` or `false`? It doesn't work as-is above because (I believe) the function finishes executing before the onload's do...

I want to be able to do something like:

```
if (check_min_sizing(input, options)) {
  // do something successful
} else {
  // throw an error
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are ways of making this work, by blocking the function until the image has loaded but its a bad thing to do. The calling code should pass in a callback function, or two if you want an error callback a well.

```
check_min_sizing(input, options, function(e){
  // do something successful
}, function(error){
  // throw an error
});
```

Comment: Bad? It's downright __*evil*__. [Fru-ets of the dev-eel](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0108174/quotes#qt0319374). It should never be thought about... ever. (Oh, BTW, the accepted answer is going to be a variant of this one so +1).

Comment: So... would the non-evil thing to do be to use a callback function, then?

Comment: Yes callbacks are simple. If you want to get fancy do some research on 'promises' in javascript.

Answer (score 0):

In asynchronous model, AMAIK there is no way to wait for callback and I think your request (architecture) is wrong basically. Whatever you want to do based on `true` or `false` result, should happen in your callback function.